# TypeError: string indices must be integers and others with JSON collections

Tags: python, json, collections

Loading json collections in Python, I found a number of problems that happen when there can be 0, 1 or more items in a collection and python switches between object not found, a dictionary object and a list of dictionaries. Looking around, I saw code trying to handle this in a variety of ways, but didn't really come across a general solution to what, I assume, must be quite a common problem when there are variable numbers of items.

Existing advice seemed to ended up with if ... elif ... else handling of the json object but this is really messy to do every time you handle an object because you end with the code to handle the object in multiple code branches.

Comment: The advice is probably right. The API should not be designed to give different structures for the same type of request. EDIT: well actually, this is a file, so whatever produces the file shouldn't be doing it this way.

Comment: @roganjosh - if you had full control of all parts of the code, this would be right. In this case, it's the widely used Newtonsoft json library that produces this file.

Comment: If you answer your question yourself that's totally fine but please try to keep the pattern of Question in the Question and then Answer the question in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of head scratching, I came up with the following pattern that resolved this and seems to work reliably if there are 0, 1 or many items in a collection.

```py
def node_list(d, k) :
    """
    handle a collection node in a json object by returning:
        an empty list if there are no child nodes at d[k],
        or a list with 1 dictionary entry if there is one child node at d[k]
        or a list of dictionaries if there are multiple child nodes at d[k]
    """ 
    if d is None : raise Exception("d is None")
    if type(d) is not dict : raise Exception("d is not a dict")
    if d.get(k) is None : return []
    if type(d.get(k)) is dict : return [d.get(k)]
    if type(d.get(k)) is not list : raise Exception("d[k] is not a dict or list")
    return d.get(k)
```

A call to process a json collection now looks like this:

```py
import json
root = json.load(open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'))
for item in node_list(root,'Item') :
   # code to handle each item here
   pass
```

Now, if there are 0,1 or many items, I get an appropriate list with 0, 1 or many items in it.